# How can I list an un-numbered section on the table of contents?

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning

Here is a capture of part of "Table of Contents" of my article.

[image]

Between section 32 and Appendix A (On Page 68), I manually added  unnumbered sections called "Summary" "Further Reading" and "Acknowledgment" by typing

```
\begin{center}
{\Large\bf Summary}
\end{center}

\begin{center}
    {\Large\bf Further Reading}
\end{center}

\begin{center}
{\Large\bf Acknowledgment}
\end{center}
```

However, I also want to add these unnumbered sections to the Table of Contents between Section 32 and Appendix A. I am afraid if I type `\section*{Summary}`instead of `\begin{center}{\Large\bf Summary}\end{center}`
the word "Summary" would not appear in the middle of the line. Nor does it seem that `\section*{Summary}` would make the Section "Summary" appear in the Table of Contents. What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{Whatever}
\lipsum[1-5]
\section*{Summary}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Summary}
\lipsum[6-10]
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

---

Don't use `\begin{center} {\Large\bf Acknowledgment} \end{center}` and `\bf`!!! I recommend something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}{\Large\bfseries}{\thesection}{2ex}{\centering}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{Whatever}
\lipsum[1-5]
\section*{Summary}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Summary}
\lipsum[6-10]
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

---

In case you don't want to center numbered sections, I recommend defining a macro. However, this way lacks consistency, so it is not good.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newcommand\yoursection[1]{%
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#1}
    \begin{center}
        \Large\bfseries#1
    \end{center}
}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{Whatever}
\lipsum[1-5]
\yoursection{Summary}
\lipsum[6-10]
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You may also use the excellent [KOMA-script](https://ctan.org/pkg/koma-script) bundle, and utilise the `addsec`-command, which gives you an unnumbered section, which behaves like all other sections. (You have similar commands for other sectioning commands `addpart`, `addchap`).

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{Whatever}
\lipsum[1-5]
\addsec{Summary}
\lipsum[6-10]
\end{document}
```

[image: Demo of addsec]